# Webforms Vs Asp.Net MVC VS2010 LoadTest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, webforms, load-testing

A colleague of mine ran a simple load test using VS2010 on a Webforms project and an Asp.net MVC project and noticed that Webforms was serving around 83 requests per second whereas Asp.net MVC was serving 28 requests per second. Both the sites were published on the same server with similar settings. 
Webforms project had 10 pages 5 of them displayed simple text messages using labels and the other 5 had text box controls. Similar functionality was built into the Asp.net MVC site so that the output is the same as the Webforms pages. Tests were run with both constant load and incremental load with similar results.
I am a little surprised with the results. Does anyone know why MVC is slower that Webforms?
Thanks!

Comment: It isn't. There is a problem with your MVC site.  Caching, perhaps?

Comment: Caching is not being used. Neither in webforms nor in mvc

Comment: Well, there really isn't enough information to answer your question. All other things being equal, ASP.NET is going to be somewhat more heavyweight, so my guess is you've got some issue with retrieving data from the database on the MVC side. Try putting some timers on your database queries to see how fast they are.

Comment: There is no database involved. All I am doing is displaying few messages using asp labels and adding few server side controls(textboxes). Same functionality on the MVC side. You can download the published files and screenshots of results from here - http://qvin.org/LoadTest.zip. I am sorry, I don't have the source code to share, but as I said it is simple functionality.

Comment: I don't really want to download a zip(sorry) but I'm curious to see what a Controller/View looks like in the example.

Comment: webforms is faster in my tests, too. mvc3:1950 rps, webforms 3500 rps. in release mode with no session & debug disabled in webconfig, with seperate integrated mode app pools on iis 7.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Without much info to go on, perhaps you should instrument your code to see what's taking a while and/or the difference between Web Forms and MVC.

You might use some aspect oriented programming techniques to remove the burden of all those logging commands.

Here's one such framework:

http://code.google.com/p/postsharp-user-plugins/wiki/Log4PostSharp